# pentaho: Openflash Chart appears blank

Tags: components, pentaho, open-flash-chart, dashboard-designer

I specified the following configuration in CDE for an openflash chart:
the name, html object, title, chart type, datasource (which uses a jdbc connection) and set 3D to true
When I click preview, all other CCC charts appear and the space reserved for the openflash chart is blank

Does the openflash chart component work?

Is there anything else I was supposed to configure that I am missing out on?

Rumbi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really answer your question without some more details (like bi-server version), but it's probably a moot point.

We haven't yet removed OpenFlashCharts from CDE because some older dashboards depend on it, but that component is very much EOL. The only "advantage" you get from it relative to CCC is that you get 3d charts (which we didn't implement in CCC because, frankly, they only make it harder to interpret the chart data). If CCC doesn't work for you (e.g. because you really really want 3d charts), I suggest you try [the Fusion Charts plugin provided by ExpandIT](http://code.google.com/p/pentaho-fc-plugin/), I believe they wrapped Fusion Charts into a CDE component.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into fusion charts.